# Error in migrate.py file in Django

Tags: python, django

I am continuously getting the following error when I try running **python manage.py runserver**

```
File "manage.py", line 14
) from exc 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Following other comments I have **activated the virtual env** and run on Python version 2.7.10 and Django version 1.11.9.

Attached below is my manage.py program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dataContractCreator.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv).
```

I even tried removing **from exc** but that still gives me errors.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: Made changes to the indentation above. But either way it's the auto generated file. I haven't altered it.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't updated this file?  I just did a clean install of django 1.11.9 with python 2.7.5.  It did not create the file you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

1. I created a python environment with `virtualenv test_env`.
2. I sourced my environment with `source test_env/bin/activate`.
3. I used `python -m pip install "django<2"` to install django.
4. `python -m django --version` provides `1.11.9`
5. Run `django-admin startproject mysite`.  This is directly from the [django projects tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/).
6. Open `mysite/manage.py`.  You see:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   import os
   import sys

   if __name__ == "__main__":

       os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
       try:
           from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
       except ImportError:
           # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
           # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
           # exceptions on Python 2.
           try:
               import django
           except ImportError:
               raise ImportError(
                   "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "                                              
                   "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you"
                   "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
               )
           raise
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   ```